# Spring Boot Cloud authentication with Google SSO and JWT token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-oauth2

I am trying to write Spring boot authentication using JWT token and Google SSO.
But when i configured SecurityContextRepository **securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)** in my security config Google SSO does not working while JWT authentication fine.
Because Google SSO does not validate in SecurityContextRepository class.

It called save function of SecurityContextRepository class.

Here is my Security Config class

```
@Autowired
private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    String[] patterns = new String[] {"/auth/**","/about"};
    return http

            .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedHandler(new JsonAccessDeniedHandler())
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(patterns).permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Login()
                .and()
            .build();


}
```

Here is my SecurityContextRepository class:

@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository  implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityContextRepository.class);

private static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange swe, SecurityContext sc) {

    System.out.println("sc.getAuthentication().getDetails() = " + sc.getAuthentication().getDetails());
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

 //   return Mono.empty();
}

@Override
public Mono load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();
    String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    String authToken = null;
    if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
        authToken = authHeader.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
    }else {
        logger.warn("couldn't find bearer string, will ignore the header.");
    }
    if (authToken != null) {
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
        return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map((authentication) -> new SecurityContextImpl((Authentication) authentication));
    } else {
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

}

How to configure oauth2Login() method with securityContextRepository.
Please, help me to find a mistake.

Comment: did youi find a solution?

Comment: I have not find a solution with cloud-gateway. Instead i used spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul